# Facebook 'sometime' cannot scrape my Wordpress site's News Article

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an Online news portal made of Wordpress. Whenever i post and article and share it to Facebook, it cannot scrape all the information. I have tried many different approaches from stackoverflow or wordpress discussion sites. I used many different plug-ins and even manually wrote the `OG-Meta-Tags` on my site. In my page, when i look at the source code, i can see that all the Facebook Meta-Tags are present in the `head` but when i go to facebook developer tool, it says some tags are missing. The main reason i can not solve it is that 40% of the times facebook can scrape all the information but rest 60% of times it cannot. This has been bugging me for a month now. Can anyone point out what is causing this problem or how i should solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it s just syntax.
Check your url here to check the markups undersood by facebook : 
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

What's your page url please?

Comment: i don't think it's the Syntax as i have mentioned, i tried plug-ins which happens to work for everybody else. And i also used the Sharing Debugger tool. This is my website: http://dailysomoyerbarta.com/

Comment: When I share in facebook it's ok. Check this page.https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

Comment: If you share several articles, you'll see that some of them are not okay. That is actually the main problem here.

Comment: Please give an example of a article causing pb. Maybe it's the permalinks

Comment: I just checked this one now. Can you look into it?
http://dailysomoyerbarta.com/2017/07/20/%e0%a6%ac%e0%a6%a8%e0%a7%8d%e0%a6%a7%e0%a7%81-%e0%a6%95%e0%a7%87-%e0%a6%b6%e0%a6%a4%e0%a7%8d%e0%a6%b0%e0%a7%81-%e0%a6%95%e0%a7%87/

Comment: Ok in fact you have no pb it's just that you need to force facebook to rescrape each page, Fb has an old version of your page in cache

Comment: We rescrape when we check on the debug tool or when we post

Comment: now get a csv import export plugin and fill lines of url have fun :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Facebook can scrape everything but it doesn't show the image when sharing. Try sharing this URL on your facebook and please let me know the problem here(placeholder for an image but there's no image) : http://dailysomoyerbarta.com/2017/07/30/lincoln/